# is there anyway we can do rotation of image in a pendulum effect in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation

is there anyway we can do rotation of image in a pendulum effect in iphone using UIView Animation or CoreAnimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CGAffineTransformRotate` to rotate your UIImageView e.g.

```
yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI * (_angle/ 180.0));
```

Also, you'll need to set up the anchor point on your image, prior to rotating it, so that you can make it `swing` from the correct position. e.g.

```
yourImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0);  // Set anchor to top middle.
```

Obviously, you'll need to set up a timer to adjust move the image and control the angle.  You could do something like the following in a timer. (untested)

```
_angle = 45;  // Set starting angle.
_direction = 1; // Set starting direction.
-(void) movePend
{
   if(_direction == 45){
      _direction = 1;
   } else if(_direction == 180) {
     _direction = 0;
   }
   _angle = (_direction) ? _angle-- : _angle++;  // Determine which way to rotate.
    yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI * (_angle/ 180.0));
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry george i need to do this without shifting the anchor point.so do you think is it possible to move the object at 0,0 with pendulum effect.

Comment: Yes.  All moving the anchor point does is align where you want the image to visually move from.  You can get around setting an anchor point by adjusting the size, location, of your swinging image.

Comment: Is there a nicer way of getting around the issue with the anchor point? It seems like a bit of a hack to just move/resize the image in IB so that we can have the pendulum effect where we want it. For example, in my case I have an image that hangs from the top centre of the screen, yet in IB I've had to move the image almost entirely out of sight so that it will appear in the right place when the app is running. It makes it really annoying to add other stuff via IB as you can't align them easily. It would be nice if there were a way round this.