# Objective C Pinned photo swing animation (like iPhoto)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, photo

I want to create animation effect like the one in iPhoto (pinned photo swing effect - see attachment). Any clues how to create that kind of animation ?

[image]

Edit:
Here is video demo of what I'm trying to do:
[CLICK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ef_uIeJFtgY)

Answer (score 1):

The concept is simple, Create the animation path(make rotation to follow the path) and animate  on anchor point. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469492/641062) is how you do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've added video demonstration of what I am trying to do. And on the swinging picture there will be some text that will be defined dynamically.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a UIImageView or any other kind of composite view- the process of animating it is the same.